# Unable to create a new branch in a repo using Bitbucket API 2.0

Tags: bitbucket, bitbucket-api

I want to create a new branch named `test-branch-name` from the `master` branch in a given repository. So as per the documentation provided [here](https://developer.atlassian.com/bitbucket/api/2/reference/resource/repositories/%7Bworkspace%7D/%7Brepo_slug%7D/refs/branches), I tried creating a new branch in the repository using Postman.

```
curl --location --request POST 'https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories/<workspace>/<repo_name>/refs/branches' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--header 'Authorization: Basic <auth_token>' \
--data-raw '{
    "name" : "test-branch-name",
    "target" : {
        "hash" : "default"
    }
}'
```

With above-mentioned request, I get this response.

```
{
    "type": "error",
    "error": {
        "fields": {
            "target.hash": "Commit not found: default"
        },
        "message": "Bad request"
    }
}
```

If, instead of the `default` hash, I put the full commit hash of the latest commit from the `master` branch in the request payload, the API call creates the branch from `develop` branch and not from `master`.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with the JSON data that you pass. Try modifying it as below.

`"{\"name\": \"{BRANCH_NAME}\", \"target\": {\"hash\": \"{SOURCE_BRANCH}\"}}"`

Replace {BRANCH_NAME} with the new branch to be created and {SOURCE_BRANCH} with the source from which it is to be created.